# A connection on fibred manifold always exists?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds

May be $\pi:Y \mapsto X$ a general fibred manifold. Is it true that in fibred manifold a connection always exists? This wiki article states this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(fibred_manifold)

Connection is an additional structure on a manifold and the manifold has to be smooth as a requirement that a connection exists. Or can connections be defined also in non-smooth manifolds?
Which manifolds have neither a metric nor a connection (any examples?)?

Answer (score 2):

You can just take a differentiable metric on the total space of the fibred bundle and define the connection to be the distribution orthogonal to the fibres.